# How to send mail using node js without nodemailer

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I tried to send mail in node js using nodemailer.

Question is: is it possible to use another framework - without nodemailer using send mail. If so - can you provide some example code?

Comment: Yes its possible with another library. Why?

Comment: @tkausl  beacuse nodemailer asking crediential.In my case without crediential send mail using node js.can please tell me library or give some code to send mail without crediential using nodejs

Comment: You can't send an email from a gmail address without credentials.

Comment: @tkausl can you please tell what are library used to send mail using node js

Answer (score 0):

You can use sendgrid to send an email. It is more reliable in my opinion. You will need to create a sendgrid account to get the API key. Then you can do something like this:

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
  to: 'test@example.com',
  from: 'test@example.com',
  subject: 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun',
  text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
  html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
};
sgMail.send(msg);
```

Comment: Did you add the api key in your environment variables?